# Modulating an oscillator by gain, pitch, and offset

Tags: c++, performance, audio, signal-processing

I've an Audio Host application that sends block of samples to a DLL I'm building. It sends 44100 samples per seconds (i.e. Sample Rate 44100hz), per block, processing 16 distinct Voices.

It processes an `Oscillator`, which plays a basic sine wave, modulated at Audio Rate by Gain, Pitch and Offset.

Here's the C++ code I have (I'm on MSVC, Release/x86 Configuration with `/02 (/Ot)` optimized settings):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

const int voiceSize = 16;
const int bufferSize = 256;
const double pi = 3.141592653589793238;
const double twopi = 2 * pi;
double sampleRate = 44100.0;
double noteFrequency = 130.81278;
double hostPitch = 1.0;

#define BOUNDED(x,lo,hi) ((x) < (lo) ? (lo) : (x) > (hi) ? (hi) : (x))

class Param
{
public:
    int mControlRate = 1;
    double mValue = 0.5;
    double mProcessedValues[voiceSize][bufferSize];
    double *pModValues;

    Param(double min, double max) {
        mMin = min;
        mMax = max;
        mRange = max - min;
    }

    inline double GetMin() { return mMin; }
    inline double GetRange() { return mRange; }
    inline double GetProcessedVoiceValue(int voiceIndex, int sampleIndex) { return mProcessedVoicesValues[voiceIndex][sampleIndex]; }

    inline void AddModulation(int voiceIndex, int blockSize) {
        double *pModVoiceValues = &pModValues[voiceIndex * bufferSize];
        double *pProcessedValues = mProcessedValues[voiceIndex];

        int i = 0;
        for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex += mControlRate, i++) {
            pProcessedValues[i] = BOUNDED(mValue + pModVoiceValues[sampleIndex], 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    }

private:
    double mMin, mMax, mRange;
    double mProcessedVoicesValues[voiceSize][bufferSize];
};
class Oscillator
{
public:
    double mRadiansPerSample = twopi / sampleRate;
    double ln2per12 = std::log(2.0) / 12.0;
    double mPhase[voiceSize];

    Param *pGain, *pOffset, *pPitch;

    Oscillator() { 
        pGain = new Param(0.0, 1.0);
        pOffset = new Param(-900.0, 900.0);
        pPitch = new Param(-48.0, 48.0);

        // reset osc phase (start at 0.0)
        for (int voiceIndex = 0; voiceIndex < voiceSize; voiceIndex++) {
            Reset(voiceIndex);
        }
    }
    ~Oscillator() {
        delete pGain;
        delete pOffset;
        delete pPitch;
    }

    void Reset(int voiceIndex) {
        mPhase[voiceIndex] = 0.0;
    }
    void ProcessVoiceBlock(int voiceIndex, int blockSize, double noteFrequency, double *left, double *right) {
        // local copy
        double phase = mPhase[voiceIndex];
        double offsetMin = pOffset->GetMin();
        double offsetRange = pOffset->GetRange();
        double pitchMin = pPitch->GetMin();
        double pitchRange = pPitch->GetRange();

        // precomputed data
        double bp0 = noteFrequency * hostPitch;

        // process block values
        for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < blockSize; sampleIndex++) {
            double value = (sin(phase)) * pGain->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex, sampleIndex);

            *left++ += value;
            *right++ += value;

            // next phase
            phase += BOUNDED(mRadiansPerSample * (bp0 * GetPitchWarped(pPitch->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex, sampleIndex), pitchMin, pitchRange) + GetOffsetWarped(pOffset->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex, sampleIndex), offsetMin, offsetRange)), 0, pi);
            while (phase >= twopi) { phase -= twopi; }
        }

        // revert local copy
        mPhase[voiceIndex] = phase;
    }
    inline double GetOffsetWarped(double normalizedValue, double min, double range) { return min + normalizedValue * range; }
    inline double GetPitchWarped(double normalizedValue, double min, double range) { return exp((min + normalizedValue * range) * ln2per12); }
};

class MyPlugin
{
public:
    double gainModValues[voiceSize][bufferSize];
    double offsetModValues[voiceSize][bufferSize];
    double pitchModValues[voiceSize][bufferSize];
    Oscillator oscillator;

    MyPlugin() {
        // link mod arrays to params
        oscillator.pGain->pModValues = gainModValues[0];
        oscillator.pOffset->pModValues = offsetModValues[0];
        oscillator.pPitch->pModValues = pitchModValues[0];

        // some fancy data for mod
        for (int voiceIndex = 0; voiceIndex < voiceSize; voiceIndex++) {
            for (int sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < bufferSize; sampleIndex++) {
                gainModValues[voiceIndex][sampleIndex] = sampleIndex / (double)bufferSize;
            }
        }
    }

    void ProcessDoubleReplace(int blockSize, double *bufferLeft, double *bufferRight) {
        // init buffer
        memset(bufferLeft, 0, blockSize * sizeof(double));
        memset(bufferRight, 0, blockSize * sizeof(double));

        // voices
        for (int voiceIndex = 0; voiceIndex < voiceSize; voiceIndex++) {
            // envelopes - here's where mod values will change, at audio rate

            // add mod to params
            oscillator.pGain->AddModulation(voiceIndex, blockSize);
            oscillator.pOffset->AddModulation(voiceIndex, blockSize);
            oscillator.pPitch->AddModulation(voiceIndex, blockSize);

            // osc buffer
            oscillator.ProcessVoiceBlock(voiceIndex, blockSize, noteFrequency, bufferLeft, bufferRight);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double bufferLeft[bufferSize];
    double bufferRight[bufferSize];

    MyPlugin myPlugin;

    // audio host call
    int numProcessing = 1024 * 50;
    int counterProcessing = 0;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (counterProcessing++ < numProcessing) {
        int blockSize = 256;
        myPlugin.ProcessDoubleReplace(blockSize, bufferLeft, bufferRight);

        // do somethings with buffer

    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "execution time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(pEnd - pStart).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Considering I'm running 16 Voices contemporaneously, it takes an huge amount of CPU for a simple Gain/Pitch/Offset modulation.

I hope I can do it better. Any tips/suggestions? Vectorizing?

Note: I could use `std::clamp` and C++17, but it doesn't matter a lot here: nothing really change with that expedient.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### counting flops

Let's unpack the inner loop, where all the work is being done. I am repeating the whole thing here, wrapping to 80 columns and adding some indentation to make it easier to read.

```
double value = sin(phase) *
        pGain->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex, sampleIndex);

*left++ += value;
*right++ += value;

// next phase
phase += BOUNDED(
        mRadiansPerSample * (
            bp0 * GetPitchWarped(pPitch->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex,
                    sampleIndex), pitchMin, pitchRange)
            + GetOffsetWarped(pOffset->GetProcessedVoiceValue(voiceIndex,
                    sampleIndex), offsetMin, offsetRange)
        ),
        0, pi
    );

while (phase >= twopi) { phase -= twopi; }

// . . .

inline double GetOffsetWarped(double normalizedValue, double min, double range)
{
    return min + normalizedValue * range;
}
inline double GetPitchWarped(double normalizedValue, double min, double range)
{
    return exp((min + normalizedValue * range) * ln2per12);
}
```

Let's see if I've got this straight. This is your program, as I understand it. You have 16 independent oscillators, each with their own time-varying frequency and gain. The frequency is a function of a pitch and an offset frequency. For now, I'll define pitch as separate from frequency (omega) in more or less the same manner you have done, switching to python for brevity: `omega = omega_C * 2**(pitch/12)`, where `omega_C = TAU*440*2**(-2 + 3/12)` is the frequency of the C below middle C. So pitch is in semitones and frequency is in rad/s. In numpy terms, you are doing the following for each oscillator:

```
# code sample 0

# Rescale user inputs.
pitches = pitch_min + pitches_raw*pitch_range
omega_offsets = omega_offset_min + omega_offsets_raw*omega_offset_range
gains = gain_min + gains_raw*gain_range

omegas = omega_C * 2**(pitches/12) + omega_offsets
values = gains*np.sin(phase0 + np.cumsum(omegas)*dt)
```

That is basically the entire program. First, the constants.

`dt` is the time in seconds between samples. `dt = 1/sample_rate`, `sample_rate = 44100`. I have written the cumulative sum using this dt to illustrate the direct correspondence to the integral over a time-varying omega that the sum is approximating.

`phase0` is the oscillator's phase at the beginning of the block you are currently processing.

`gains`, `pitches`, and `omega_offsets` are three floating point user inputs, gains and pitches possibly being mapped to an after touch MIDI keyboard with a pitch bend and omega_offsets mapped to a sweet MIDI slider, all being sampled at the audio sample rate. They are being represented as numpy vectors, hence the esses. `Gains` ranges from 0 to 1, `pitches` ranges from 4 octaves below omega_C to 4 octaves above omega_C, and `omega_offsets` ranges from -900Hz to 900Hz. (Incidentally, your gain min and max are not being used!) That offset frequency is super weird and kinda cool. That makes no sense from a conventional music theory standpoint. With any offset at all, pitch will no longer match up with octaves. I'd actually like to hear what that sounds like.

You could have made it easier for the reader to figure all that out. If I didn't already have some idea what to look for, I would have been completely lost. You should find a way to get your code to look as much like code sample 0 as possible.

Anyway, how fast *should* this loop run? How many flops does this loop translate to? Counting the number of operations *per sample* and using code sample 0 as a guide, I count 5 +s, 7 *s, an exp and a sin. Adding another + for when the 16 voices are added, that's 6 +s. Using [this benchmark](http://www.latkin.org/blog/2014/11/09/a-simple-benchmark-of-various-math-operations/) as a rough guideline, that translates to 6 + 7 + 10 + 15 = 38 flops per sample per voice. Multiplying by 16 voices and 44100 samples per second, that's **27 megaflops**. A 1 GHz processor has a thousand cycles to do just 27 of those calculations. You should be seeing almost zero CPU on your toaster. There's something else going on here.

In fact, there's nothing wrong with your code. It was your benchmark. See the epilogue. But I left all these suggestions here anyway if for some reason you want your code to go even faster.

#### small loops

Your code might be slower than it could be because your inner loop is too big. Loops run fastest when they are as small as possible. This is because the fastest memory your system has—registers—is in extremely limited supply. If your loop is too big, the system runs out of registers and it has to use slower memory to run the loop. You can break up that inner loop into smaller loops—one per line of code in code sample 0 should work OK. In theory, that should make your code run faster. But the compiler is actually able to figure out most of that, since everything is contained in a single file. It is able to inline whatever it wants and reorder execution however it wants, because it knows what every function is actually doing. This idea is closely related to vectorisation.

#### vectorising

You're doing the same operations `blockSize` times. You should be able to speed that up with simd. The [Intel MKL has simd-accelerated vectorised sin(), etc.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-v-sin) that you can use. Code sample 0 gives you a basic idea of what the vectorised code is going to look like. The MKL docs don't give an example, so I'll give one now. As a reminder, you really don't have to do this. See the epilogue.

```
#include <mkl.h>

// determines the size of a static array.
#define SASIZE(sa) (sizeof(sa)/sizeof(*sa))

// . . .

float phases[] = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f, 5.f};
float sin_phases[SASIZE(phases)];
vsSin(SASIZE(phases), phases, sin_phases);
// Now, sin_phases[i] = sin(phases[i]). All of the sin()s were computed
// all at once, about 4 or 8 at a time using simd instructions.
```

#### float

This is all audio data, so you don't need doubles. Floats will work just fine, and they'll be way way faster, especially after you get simd working.

#### integral phase

You can store and manipulate phase using `uint32_t`s. It is naturally modular with modulus 2**32, so you never need to do any `fmod`s or subtractions, especially repeated subtractions in a loop.

```
            while (phase >= twopi) { phase -= twopi; }  // idk about this...
```

That there is some weirdness. The mod 2**32 happens automatically when converting from float, adding, subtracting, whatever, so it should be a lot faster and a lot more accurate. You should only convert back to float phase before a sin operation or something like that. Here's an example. I also included an example of how to do the same modulo operation in all floating point numbers.

```
#include <cstdio>  // Hey, I like *printf().
#include <cinttypes>

// These are actually templated C++ math functions. The c doesn't
// stand for C, I guess...
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define TAU 6.283185307179586


// fmodf, but always rounding toward negative infinity.
// The output will always be in [0, y). This is not the case
// with fmod(). See man fmod.
float fmodf_rd(float x, float y)
{
    float r = fmod(x, y);
    return r < 0.f? r + y : r;
}
uint32_t integral_phase(float phi)
{
    return phi / (float)TAU * 0x1p32f;
}
float float_phase(uint32_t phi_i)
{
    return (float)phi_i * (float)TAU * 0x1p-32f;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // Phases, in radians.
    float alpha = TAU/12., beta = atan(2.f);
    uint32_t alpha_i = integral_phase(alpha), beta_i = integral_phase(beta);

    // Phase calculations in radians and floating point:
    float gamma = fmodf_rd(5.f*alpha - 7.f*beta, (float)TAU);
    // The same phase calculation in integral phase. Note there is no
    // mod operation at all.
    uint32_t gamma_i = 5*alpha_i - 7*beta_i;


    printf("difference = %.9g\n", (double)(float_phase(gamma_i) - gamma));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Epilogue: An M. Night Shyamalan twist.

This has been bothering me enough that I finally ran your code. You were saying you were getting slow results, but your code, though a little funky, did not look particularly slow actually. So I assumed it was something wrong with your benchmark. I nuked the C++ `chrono` badness and replaced it with `dtime(),` a wrapper I wrote around `clock_gettime()`. `dtime()` returns the current value of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in seconds as a double. I also redid the benchmark math, outputting the performance in terms of %CPU. This is the diff:

```
--- mod.cpp-    2018-11-20 03:19:11.091296221 -0500
+++ mod.cpp 2018-11-20 03:39:39.529689861 -0500
@@ -1,7 +1,21 @@
-#include <iostream>
+#include <stdio.h>
+#include <time.h>
+#include <assert.h>
+
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cmath>
-#include <chrono>
+
+double timespec_to_d(struct timespec *ts)
+{
+    return (double)ts->tv_sec + 1e-9*(double)ts->tv_nsec;
+}
+double dtime(void)
+{
+    struct timespec ts;
+    int res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
+    assert(res == 0);
+    return timespec_to_d(&ts);
+}

 const int voiceSize = 16;
 const int bufferSize = 256;
@@ -154,7 +168,7 @@
     // audio host call
     int numProcessing = 1024 * 50;
     int counterProcessing = 0;
-    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
+    double t0 = dtime();
     while (counterProcessing++ < numProcessing) {
         int blockSize = 256;
         myPlugin.ProcessDoubleReplace(blockSize, bufferLeft, bufferRight);
@@ -162,6 +176,8 @@
         // do somethings with buffer

     }
-    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point pEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
-    std::cout << "execution time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(pEnd - pStart).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
+    double dt_busy = (dtime() - t0)/numProcessing/bufferSize,
+           dt_total = 1./sampleRate;
+    printf("CPU = %.6g %%\n", dt_busy/dt_total);
+    return 0;
 }
```

`dt_busy` is the total amount of time your code takes to process a single sample. `dt_total`, the time between samples, is the total amount of time your code has to process a single sample. Divide the two and you predict %CPU usage while your DLL is running.

*aaaaaaand* this is the output:

```
% g++ -o mod mod.cpp
% ./mod                 
CPU = 0.105791 %
%
```

When running as a plugin with realtime user input streams, your code will use .1% CPU. It was your benchmark the entire time.

Comment: Frequency offset, when set to 0, doesn't add offset, so pitch is perfectly tuned in octaves.

Comment: Can you give to me an example with simd sin and vectorization? I've no idea how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, when set to zero. For every other value, though, lol

Comment: for electronic music and "kickdrum synth" is a good tweak :)

Comment: also: why on code sample 0 do you use "pow" instead of exp? Its way slower...

Comment: I was aiming at brevity, which was the reason I had switched to python in the first place. Also, numpy will fool you. It automatically detects constant base inputs and replaces c\*\*x with exp(x\*log(c)). After that first calculation of log(c), the speed will be identical. Without the numpy arrays, though, yeah, you're right.

Actually, even a decent C compiler should do the same trick. They understand the functions of the standard math library. If it sees the x in pow(x, y) doesn't change over a whole loop, it will replace it with exp(y*log(x)) and calculate the log(x) only once.

Comment: those C compilers are pretty freaking clever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86001/discussion-between-enigmaticphysicist-and-markzzz).

Answer (score 5):

- Don't define pi and twopi yourself. They should be available from math.h as `M_PI` and `M_2_PI` if you're in the GNU stack.
- Defining functions as `inline` is more or less useless. The compiler will do this (or not) as it sees fit, and generally knows better than you on when it's beneficial.
- `GetMin()` should be `GetMin() const`. Same for `GetRange`, `GetProcessedVoiceValue`, and anything that doesn't modify a class member.
- `while (phase >= twopi) { phase -= twopi; }` - This should not be a loop. It can be done in O(1), something like `phase = fmod(phase, twopi)` - but double-check this. For very small values of `phase`, `fmod` may actually be slower. You can also try `phase -= twopi*int(phase/twopi)` which is also O(1).
- On this line:

`double *pModVoiceValues = &pModValues[voiceIndex * bufferSize];`

You're dereferencing and then re-referencing a pointer, which you don't need to do. Simply add:

`double *pModVoiceValues = pModValues + voiceIndex*bufferSize;`

Comment: `M_PI` and `M_2_PI` are not standard C++ identifiers.  That said, your reasoning is correct; we can compute suitable values. `const auto pi = 4.0 * std::atan(1)`, for example.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks; I guess those are Gnu-specific.

Comment: @Reinderien; nice suggestions. But unfortunately they don't improve the speed of the program.

Comment: @markzzz The `fmod` will improve program speed, if only imperceptibly.

Comment: curious: fmod slow down the process here :O

Comment: It's possible that the loop is more efficient in the case where phase is typically a very small multiple of 2pi. If your intent is hyper-optimization, you could stick with the loop.

Comment: @markzzz I edited my answer to provide another alternative.

Comment: Those mathematical constants are a part of POSIX XSI, so if you're using linux, you are pretty much guaranteed those mathematical constants. See `$ man 0p math.h` on most UNIXey systems. You must `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before you include math.h, or any other header you want to use POSIX XSI features from. See `$ man feature_test_macros`.

Comment: And `M_2_PI` will not do what you want. It equals `2./M_PI`. So, you really will need to define `2*M_PI` yourself.

Comment: @Reinderien: even with the new phase mod, its the same speed more or less, nothing change.

Answer (score 4):

## General overview

I found this hard to follow.  The logic is scattered across several coupled classes without a clear idea of a specific single responsibility for each class.

The class, function and variable names aren't as helpful as they could be - for example, `GetProcessedVoiceValue()` doesn't indicate what kind of processing was done; `ln2per12` only captures *how* it was computed, rather than what it's *for*, and `MyPlugin` looks like a generic temporary name.

## Specific issues

`BOUNDED()` is a dangerous macro - it expands its arguments more than once, meaning that any side-effects can be multiply executed, unlike the equivalent function call.  Prefer to use a function - either `std::clamp()` or your own version of it (if you need to build with old compilers).  Such a functions is generally a zero-cost abstraction in C++.

Variable-length arrays are not standard C++.  Fix this by making `voiceSize` and `bufferSize` *compile-time* constants, aka `constexpr` (rather than plain `const`).

Prefer initialisation to assignment.  In `Param`, for example, we could make `mMin`, `mMax` and `mRange` const if we initialize:

```
    Param(double min, double max)
        : mMin{min},
          // mMax was never used, so don't store it
          mRange{max - min}
    {
    }

    // make them public, so we don't need `get_min()` etc.
    const double mMin, mRange;
```

The uninitialised `pModValues` pointer is especially dangerous here.

I don't understand why we're updating `left` and `right` identically.  We can get better special locality by writing just one of them, and (if we really need two identical buffers) using `std::copy()` to duplicate it afterwards.

In `Oscillator`, there's no need for `pGain`, `pOffset` and `pPitch` to be pointers.  Eliminate the memory allocation (and risk of leaks when one of them throws `std::bad_alloc`) by making them simple member variables - don't write Java code!

```
Param pGain, pOffset, pPitch;

Oscillator()
    : pGain{0.0, 1.0},
      pOffset{-900.0, 900.0},
      pPitch{-48.0, 48.0}
{ /* ... */ }

// destructor is now defaulted
```

Some functions from `<cmath>` wrongly accessed in the global namespace (namely `std::sin()` and `std::exp()`); also `std::memset()` from `<cstring>`.  These should be correctly qualified for portable code.

Prefer `std::fill()` or `std::fill_n()` over `std::memset()` - the former takes care of conversions and constructors where necessary, and is equivalent to the latter in simple cases, so it's a good habit to acquire:

```
    std::fill_n(bufferLeft, blockSize, 0);
    std::fill_n(bufferRight, blockSize, 0);
```

Declare `main()` with no arguments when not intending to process command-line options.

If you can, make sure your compiler targets the particular hardware you'll be using (for me the speed more than doubles when I add `-O3 -march=native` to my compilation command).

Comment: BOUNDED: What do you mean "evalutate its arguments more than once"?

Comment: `BOUNDED` expands `x` three times.  That's  misleading if `x` is an expression with side-effects (e.g. `*p++`) - it's very different from a function call.  Similarly for the other arguments that appear multiple times in the expansion.  That's why we use all-caps for macro names, but it's better to avoid the problem by using a function instead.  There's usually no cost to that in C++.

Comment: I see. anyway, I've applied most of your suggestions, nothing change :) Compiler targets its the max I can (O2, or Ox in MSVC). Dunno its that!

Comment: The logic of the program is: having a DLL (MyPlugin), call the ProcessDoubleReplace from a Host that load that DLL. The plugin need to take each param value and sum modulations values (which change across time). Once processed, I must apply these params (3 in this case: gain, pitch, offset) and produce audio (sine wave in this case). That's all, considering it process per voices :) Note: left and right is because signal is stereo, and in the future I could process them separately).

Answer (score 1):

I'm filing this as a separate answer because it's on a very different topic from my previous one. You have a constant for note frequency, but (a) it isn't precise and (b) you should compute it rather than writing the constant.

$$12 \log_2 \frac {130.81278} {55} \approx 15$$

$$f = 55 \times 2^{15/12} = 110 \times 2^{1/4}$$

$$f \approx 130.812,782,650,299...$$

In C,

```
const double noteFrequency = 110*pow(2, 0.25);
```